# Is it possible to scale out Karate automated tests to multiple slave VMs or Kubernetes clusters?

Tags: database, kubernetes, automated-tests, distributed-computing, karate

I have a lot of karate tests that runs for hours. I am already running them in parallel to the maximum limit allowed by my machine. I have several Virtual Machines that I use as part of my selenium Grid for functional tests. Is there a way I can utilize those VMs to scale out my Karate tests too?

Comment: We are working on this right now. Hope we can count on you to beta-test this. You can monitor our twitter feed for updates.